# Taking in multiple inputs at once and then giving out output at once

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

So my question is how to efficiently write a program where in we are able to take multiple inputs (the amount of inputs given is determined by the user) and then give the outputs at once. Lets consider a program which gives gives the sum of its digits. Eg - 12345 = 15.

```
//Single input single output 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T, N;
    cout << "Enter the value of T (No. of test cases)" << endl;
    cin >> T;
    cout << "Enter the value of N : " << endl;
    while (T > 0)
    {
        cin >> N;

        int ans = 0,temp1,temp2;
        while(N!=0)
        {
            temp1= N %10;
            N = (N - temp1)/10;
            ans = ans + temp1;
        }
        cout << ans << endl;
        T--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Taking in all inputs then giving out all outputs ( Not working properly)

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int SumCal(int Number, int TestCase, int t);
int main()
{
    int N, T;

    cout << " Enter the value of T ( Total number of test cases) " << endl;
    cin >> T;
    int *Ans(new int[T]);
    if (T >= 1 && T <= 1000)
    {
        cout << "Enter the value of N" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++)
        {
            cin >> N;
            if (N >= 1 && N <= 100000)
                Ans[i] = SumCal(N, i, T);
        }
    }

    for (int z = 1; z <= T; z++)
    {
        cout << Ans[z] << endl;
    }


    delete[] Ans;
    return 0;
}

int SumCal(int Number, int TestCase, int t)
{
    int temp1, temp2 = 0;
    int *AnsTemp(new int[t]);

    temp1 = Number % 10;

    temp2 = Number / 10;
    if (temp2 < 10 && temp2 > 0)
        AnsTemp[TestCase] = (temp1 + temp2);


    while (temp2 > 10)
    {
        AnsTemp[TestCase] = (AnsTemp[TestCase] + temp1);
        temp2 = temp2 / 10;
        temp1 = temp1 % 10;
    }

    return AnsTemp[TestCase];
    delete[] AnsTemp;
}
```

```
// This will work properly for multiple inputs multiple outputs

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int SumCal(int Number, int TestCase);
int main()
{
    int N, T;

    cout << " Enter the value of T ( Total number of test cases) " << endl;
    cin >> T;
    int Ans[1000] = {};
    if (T >= 1 && T <= 1000)
    {
        cout << "Enter the value of N" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++)
        {
            cin >> N;
            if (N >= 1 && N <= 100000)
                Ans[i] = SumCal(N, i);
        }
    }

    for (int z = 1; z <= T; z++)
    {
        cout << Ans[z] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int SumCal(int Number, int TestCase)
{
    int temp1, temp2 = 0;
    int ans;

    temp1 = Number % 10;

    temp2 = Number / 10;
    if (temp2 < 10 && temp2 > 0)
        ans = (temp1 + temp2);

    while (temp2 > 10)
    {
        ans = (ans + temp1);
        temp2 = temp2 / 10;
        temp1 = temp2 % 10;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

These are the codes I could think of. The first one is a simple one, which takes in an input and then gives out a output. In the second one I tried to use dynamic memory allocation but the program gives error. ( I know I haven't made proper use of * and & in it but I already tried using it in various manners and failed). The third program is successful but as we are setting up a large constraint value to the array, (i.e int Ans[1000]) it makes the program a bit inefficient.

So my question is how would one dynamically allocate memory during runtime successfully to take in multiple inputs and then give multiple outputs at once.

Comment: *Please*, post the code in the actual post. Links die, and are not usually inviting for those trying to help.

Comment: @Mr_Feynman If this is the actual code formatting I understand your struggle.

Comment: @Mr_Feynman What for is the `int *AnsTemp;` in the second example? Are you using it as array? No.

Comment: @LogicStuff I just copy+pasted the code that was originally put at a very poor pastebin service (that is the real formatting of the code), in either case; this question should be closed as too broad. I originally edited the code into the question to see if *OP* would clearify intent by modifying the question, but this seems not to be the case.

Comment: Sorry about my formatting. Yes I wanted to use it as a dynamic array.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to work with your code. I just took the 1st example, minimized the code and did what you should have done:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cout << "Enter the value of T (No. of test cases)" << endl;
    cin >> T;
    int *buf = new int[T]();              // buffer to hold the answers

    for(int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
    {
        int N;
        cout << "Enter the value of N : " << endl;
        cin >> N;

        while(N)
        {
            buf[i] += N % 10;             // calculate on the buffer element
            N /= 10;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
        cout << buf[i] << endl;           // print the buffer

    delete [] buf;                        // delete buffer
    return 0;
}
```

There's not much to do for managing the dynamically allocated array here, but take a look at `std::vector` and its uses.

Comment: Wow, thank you that's exactly what I was looking for! I don't get it properly though. If *buf is a pointer why does buf[i] += N % 10 works? Why was there no need to point to the address of N%10 i.e & N% 10

Comment: `buf` is `int*`, `buf[i]` is `int`, there's no need to store addresses and you certainly cannot take an address of a temporary (`N % 10`).

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer. Sorry to push, but it's common with newbies.